# Divergence of an alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I need to test this numerical series for convergence:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n}\times 2^{4n}}{n\times3^{2n} }$$

My first idea was to use the Leibniz's test for alternating series, but turns out this sequence is non-decreasing:
$$ a_{n} = \frac{ 2^{4n}}{n\times3^{2n} } $$

Which is one of the conditions of the Leibnitz's test. Does this mean the series is divergent?

Comment: The sequence $a_n$ does not tend to $0.$ It tends to $\infty.$

Comment: Write the general term under the form $\dfrac {a^n}n$ and discuss the value of $a$. Recall that $\sum a^n$ and $\sum n^\alpha a^n$ have the same behavior due to the ratio test.

Answer (score 3):

No, Leibniz's test tells you that if your sequence verifies some conditions, THEN the series is convergent. It does not tell anything more. In particular if one of the conditions is not satisfied, nothing can be said.

For your problem, is it often useful to use the ratio test when you see that simplifications can be made : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test.

You don't even need it here since the sequence you are summing does not converge to $0$, meaning the series is definitely not converging.

Comment: Can you use the Ratio test for a series which contains negative terms?

Comment: Yes, the version I know allows it and moreover you take the ratio with absolute value so it does not matter if the sequence has negative terms.

Answer (score 2):

Note that eventually $\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)^{2n}\ge n$ and then

$$ \frac{ 2^{4n}}{n\times3^{2n} }= \frac{ 4^{2n}}{n\times3^{2n} }\ge \frac{ 4^{2n}}{\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)^{2n}\times3^{2n} }=\left(\frac{8}{7}\right)^{2n}$$